# Is it normal to use $broadcast in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a search controller, where the user can search for a single area.
After an area is searched, I $rootScope.$broadcast that the area has changed.

I have various other controllers that are responsible for independently loading and showing data about that area. They use $rootScope.$on, and get extra information from other sources using $http.

Is my approach the normal way of doing things? It feels unusual, since $broadcast wasn't mentioned in the tutorials I have been through.

I am trying to learn angular.

Comment: i bet they were mentioned in a lot of other tutorials, `$broadcast` is part of the API after all

Comment: There are many tutorials, for sure. Most of what I have seen are products / items pages. My question is vague, but I don't know where to start looking. Other people have asked similar questions, about communication between controllers, I just feel I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$emit/$broadcast are used a lot in angular libraries and even 3rd parties.

For instance you have events when navigating using the ng-route module, $routeChangeStart, $routeChangeSuccess, ... same goes for the 3rd party ui-router : $stateChangeStart, $stateChangeSuccess,....

It's just an event bus : listening and sending events in order to communicate with external components.

In angularJS, you will find them in the event part of the documentation.

However you should be carefull with events, too many of them can lead to lost control of what you're code is doing or be able to tell what should be the current state of your app.

It's possible for some that a cleaner way of doing it is tostore data in $rootScope/a service an use $watch on them.

EDIT : i didn't mention it but storing data in $rootScope is not advised for design/reusability.isoltion purpose.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to recommend polluting the `$rootScope` would be much better to implement a Service like you suggest

Comment: +1 for `It's just an event bus`. Anyway I would also not recommend to store data in $rootScope (at least not primarly).

Comment: As far as I know, I am not storing data at the $rootScope, other than the event handler itself. All the data I then need is then passed through the event arguments. Is that okay, or is it still better to use a service?

Comment: That's totally dependant on your use case. But the example i mentionned are services that emits events, not controllers. So i guess that emitting events fit more in a service layer than a controller layer. But i'm not really good at event designing so can't really say